# How to test for a file in cache?

Tags: android

I am trying to test for this cache in my asyncTask. How would i go about doing this?

```
public void putBitmapInDiskCache(URI imageUri, Bitmap avatar) {   
    File cacheDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails");
    cacheDir.mkdirs();
    File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, ""+imageUri.hashCode());   
    try {      
            cacheFile.createNewFile();       
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);    
            avatar.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);       
            fos.flush();       
            fos.close();    
          } catch (Exception e) {       
            Log.e("error", "Error when saving image to cache. ", e);    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you have. If prior to your call to createNewFile() you were to check if it exists, you can do whatever needs to be done there

```
 if (cacheFile.exists()) { ... } else { cacheFile.createNewFile() }
```