# Caching files using getCacheDir()

Tags: android, caching, dropbox

I wanted to download images that are downloaded from Dropbox and cache them for further use:

```
String cachePath = mContext.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + entry.fileName();
File cacheFile = new File(cachePath);
//cacheFile.exists() returns true after 1st call
if(!cacheFile.exists()){
  //If cache doesn't exist, download the file
  mFos = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
  mApi.getThumbnail(path, mFos, ThumbSize.BESTFIT_320x240,
                              ThumbFormat.JPEG, null);
}
mDrawable = Drawable.createFromPath(cachePath);
mImageView.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
```

The `mDrawable` is `null` if the code doesn't enter the if block.

If I comment the if condition it works fine. But downloads the images every time.

**Edit:**

The above code is from [how to test for a file in cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880990/how-to-test-for-a-file-in-cache)

Answer (score 8):

Try this hope helps you

```
String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + entry.fileName();
        File file = new File(path);

        if (file.exists()) {
            // File exists
        } else {
            // File does not exist
        }
```

Comment: I checked the file path, its fine: `/data/data/com.example.myapp/cache/image.jpg`. Moreover if I comment the file exists check, it works fine. So, no problem with the path i guess